# Cumulative sum, refreshing at intervals, python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have some timestamped data, and I would like to run an expanding sum, that will refresh, say every day at 7:00 (restart from zero), kind of a "saw-teeth" sum.
How can I do that in pandas?
Thank you very much,
JT2

Comment: Hello, [Please provide a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) , you can take a look at  [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1. simplest case is to `groupby()` the `floor("D")` of the date.  To meet your requirement, subtract 7 hours before doing floor
2. then use `transform("cumsum")` so you get the running total with same cardinality of original dataframe
3. showed results for 6am and 7am where you see totals are resetting

```
import pandas as pd
import random
df = pd.DataFrame([{'DATE':d, "value":random.randint(0,10)}
 for d in pd.date_range(start=datetime(2020,7,24),end=datetime(2020,7,30), freq="15min")])

df["cumsum"] = df.groupby((df["DATE"]-pd.Timestamp(1970,1,1,7)).dt.floor("D"))["value"].transform("cumsum")

df[df["DATE"].dt.hour.isin([6,7])][:15]
```

**output**

```
               DATE  value  cumsum
2020-07-24 06:00:00      3     137
2020-07-24 06:15:00      0     137
2020-07-24 06:30:00      6     143
2020-07-24 06:45:00      7     150
2020-07-24 07:00:00      0       0
2020-07-24 07:15:00      3       3
2020-07-24 07:30:00     10      13
2020-07-24 07:45:00      5      18
2020-07-25 06:00:00      6     459
2020-07-25 06:15:00     10     469
2020-07-25 06:30:00      8     477
2020-07-25 06:45:00      8     485
2020-07-25 07:00:00      3       3
2020-07-25 07:15:00      4       7
2020-07-25 07:30:00      0       7
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your DataFrame contains:

```
Dat               Amount
2020-07-01 10:00   10.0
2020-07-02 06:50    3.1
2020-07-02 07:00    1.0
2020-07-02 08:10    2.1
2020-07-03 05:00    3.2
2020-07-03 10:00   12.0
2020-07-03 13:10    8.0
```

To perform your grouping and expanding sum, you can run:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Dat', freq='24H', base=7)).Amount.expanding().sum()
```

For the above data sample, the result is:

```
Dat                   
2020-07-01 07:00:00  0    10.0
                     1    13.1
2020-07-02 07:00:00  2     1.0
                     3     3.1
                     4     6.3
2020-07-03 07:00:00  5    12.0
                     6    20.0
Name: Amount, dtype: float64
```

You perform grouping by *24 hour* periods (days), but *base* shifts
the start of day just by 7 hours.